# is it possible to use jsonwebtoken in brower

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript

I want to parse the JWT token, and found this jsonwebtoken lib https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken, it seems designed for NodeJS. is it possible to use this lib with browser? I have tried but facing this error:

```
ymmetricKeyDetailsSupported.js:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at ./node_modules/jsonwebtoken/lib/asymmetricKeyDetailsSupported.js (asymmetricKeyDetailsSupported.js:3:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
    at ./node_modules/jsonwebtoken/lib/validateAsymmetricKey.js (validateAsymmetricKey.js:1:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
    at ./node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js (verify.js:6:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
.
```

seems there some issue with browser. what should I do to fixed this issue? the process seems only nodejs contains that did not exists in browser. This is my typescript code:

```
isTokenNeedRefresh: (seconds: number) => {
        const accessToken = localStorage.getItem(WheelGlobal.ACCESS_TOKEN_NAME);
        const decodedToken = jwt.verify(accessToken, "secret");
        const exp = decodedToken.exp;
        const now = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
        // seconds was the token prereload time gap
        const isExpired = exp < now + seconds;
        if (isExpired) {
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why would you? To verify the JWT client-side you'd have to have the secret, and then it's _not secret_.

Comment: I want to check the jwt token expire or not to pre refresh the token. JWT token no need to keep secret, it could parse in anywhere.

Comment: Although verifying will check whether it's expired, you don't _need_ to verify (and _cannot_ without the secret) to check that. If you know the structure of a JWT it's straightforward to split, parse and read the `exp` claim (and if you don't https://jwt.io/ is a good intro).

Comment: ok, I will try what you said, maybe we did not need this lib to parse the JWT token.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion, design-wise, it's not a good practice to decode JWT on the browser side and extract the header or payload to see if it expired or not, it's better to retrieve the expiration time as a property when you are receiving the token and store and retrieve it when you need it, something like:

```json
{
"access_token": <SOME JWT TOKEN>
"expire_in": <SOME DATE OR UNIX TIMESTAMP>
...
}
```

But if you want to do this anyway, since the JWT header and payload are encoded in  `base64url-encoded format` you can use `window.atob` to parse it.
for `headers` it would be like this:

```js
const jwt = '<YOUR JWT TOKEN>';
const headerBase64 = jwt.split('.')[0];
const base64 = headerBase64.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/');
const decodedHeaders = JSON.parse(window.atob(base64));

console.log(decodedHeaders);
```

The same also applies to the `payload` of your JWT:

```js
const jwt = '<YOUR JWT TOKEN>';
const payloadBase64 = jwt.split('.')[1];
const base64 = payloadBase64.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/');
const decodedJwt = JSON.parse(window.atob(base64));

console.log(decodedJwt);
```

I hope that helps you with the problem